# Error in element to be cloned below particular division

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying two label fields and their respective text fields cloned after div id/class containing it using button. But it gets append above, i want it below.
I tried append and afterThis plugins of JQuery.
Check this out.
[Demo: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpa4m7vr/)

Please Help me. Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
 $("#cloneadd").click(function() {
  var clone ='<tr id="e00">'; 
  clone +='<td colspan=1><label>Amount :</label></td>'; 
  clone +='<td colspan=1><label>Detail :</label></td>' ;
  clone +='</tr>';
  clone +='<tr id="e01">';
  clone +='<td colspan=1 id="opt_1"><input type="text" name="amt_exp" onkeypress="return isNum(event)" placeholder="Amount"/></td>';
  clone +='<td colspan=1 id="opt_2"><input type="text" name="det_exp" placeholder="Detail"/></td>';
  clone +='</tr>';
  /*$("#expopt").append($(clone));*/
  $(clone).insertAfter( "#expopt" );
 });
});
```

```html
<form action="xyz">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <label>Annual Amount :</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="text" name="ann_amo" onkeypress="return isNum(event)" placeholder="Enter Amount" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <label>Info :</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="text" name="ann_inf" placeholder="Enter Details" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div id="expopt">
            <tr id="e00">
                <td colspan=1>
                    <label>Amount :</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>
                    <label>Detail :</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="e01">
              <td colspan=1 id="opt_1">
               <input type="text" name="amt_exp" onkeypress="returnisNum(event)"/>
              </td>
              <td colspan=1 id="opt_2">
               <input type="text" name="det_exp" placeholder="Detail" />
              </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="button" id="cloneadd" value="ADD"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert it above the `tr` of the button

```
$(clone).insertBefore( $(this).closest('tr'));
```

---

Your html is invalid, table can't have `div` as a child, to group `tr` elements use `tbody`

```
<form action="xyz">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <label>Annual Amount :</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="text" name="ann_amo" onkeypress="return isNum(event)" placeholder="Enter Amount" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <label>Info :</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="text" name="ann_inf" placeholder="Enter Details" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="expopt">
            <tr id="e00">
                <td colspan=1>
                    <label>Amount :</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>
                    <label>Detail :</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="e01">
                <td colspan=1 id="opt_1">
                    <input type="text" name="amt_exp" onkeypress="returnisNum(event)" />
                </td>
                <td colspan=1 id="opt_2">
                    <input type="text" name="det_exp" placeholder="Detail" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="button" id="cloneadd" value="ADD" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

then

```
$(function () {
    $("#cloneadd").click(function () {
        var clone = '<tr id="e00">';
        clone += '<td colspan=1><label>Amount :</label></td>';
        clone += '<td colspan=1><label>Detail :</label></td>';
        clone += '</tr>';
        clone += '<tr id="e01">';
        clone += '<td colspan=1 id="opt_1"><input type="text" name="amt_exp" onkeypress="return isNum(event)" placeholder="Amount"/></td>';
        clone += '<td colspan=1 id="opt_2"><input type="text" name="det_exp" placeholder="Detail"/></td>';
        clone += '</tr>';
        //or $(clone).appendTo('#expopt');
        $(clone).insertAfter('#expopt');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cpna3ba4/)

Answer (score 1):

Guess this file 'll helps You : http://jsfiddle.net/cpna3ba4/3/

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $("#cloneadd").click(function () {
        i = i+1;
        //$(clone).appendTo('#expopt');
        var clonTrHeading = $('#e00').clone().attr({'id':'e00'+i});
        var clonTrInput = $('#e01').clone().attr({'id':'e01'+i});  
        clonTrInput.find('input').val('');
        $('#expopt tr:last').after(clonTrHeading);
        $('#expopt tr:last').after(clonTrInput);
    });
});
```